# find the longest substring want to make code faster

Tags: python, optimization

trying to find the longest substring of string

> "abcdab"'s longest substring is "abcd"
>   
>  Given a string, find the length of the longest substring without 
>    repeating characters.

```
 def lengthOfLongestSubstring(self, s):
        """
        :type s: str
        :rtype: int
        """
        result = ""
        result_temp = ""
        for i in range(len(s)+1):
            for j in range(i+1,len(s)+1):
                if (len(result_temp) <= len(s[i:j])) and  (s[i:j][-1:] not in result_temp):
                    result_temp = s[i:j]
                else:
                    result = result_temp if len(result) < len(result_temp) else result
                    result_temp = ""
                    break
        result = result_temp if len(result) < len(result_temp) else result
        return len(result)
```

I want to make this code much faster 
is there way to make code faster?

Comment: Given a string, find the length of the longest substring without repeating characters.

Comment: @AlexanderZhang: The "longest substring" problem is *usually* short for "longest common substring" (between two different strings). I'll admit the posted code doesn't seem to fit this (there is only one string involved); I may have added that tag erroneously. **Edit:** Yeah, added erroneously, I've removed the tag.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A different way called [sliding window algorithm](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/window-sliding-technique) to do this.

```
def lengthOfLongestSubstring(self, s: str) -> int:
    substring, length, max_len = "", 0, 0
    for c in s:
        if c in substring:
            index = substring.find(c)
            substring = substring[(index + 1)::]
        substring += c
        length = len(substring)
        if length > max_len:
            max_len = length

    return max_len
```

Comment: thx Compilcated. can you explain why my code is not efficient?

Comment: You code's time complexity is O(n^2), it  repeatedly check whether a char exists or not.

Answer (score 0):

Here's another approach to this problem:

The length of the longest substring without repeated characters obviously can't be greater than the size of the alphabet. So we can loop over all substrings of the greatest possible length, and then all substrings one character shorter than that, and so on until we find a substring without repeated characters. If such substring of length `i` exists, than a substring with length `i - 1` also exists, so we can use binary search to further speed this up. We can also use a set data structure which we update as we loop over the substrings in order to quickly check if a substring has repeated characters.